# Possible to pause console operation?

Tags: cpu, job-control

I have many working jobs running on different consoles.

They almost occupied all the CPU usage, which caused me hard to control the system ( very slow response time )

Is there any way to pause these consoles? or any other ways?

#update

I am actually building Yocto in many different consoles, it seems hard to adjust a specific process, and when building Yocto, there are many different processes running, and they may end and start another new one repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to pause a process:

1. Send a SIGSTOP to the the process to freeze it (SIGCONT to unfreeze). You can also hit Ctrl+S (Ctrl+Q) to send these signals to an active process. But if it is in background, you would have to use `kill` or its variations.
2. Use `nice` to set priorities to processes. By default, all user processes are set to 10 and therefore get equal CPU. If the process is not important and can be slowed down - rise the niceness. If a process needs to have a priority - reduce the niceness.
3. Just stop unneeded processes :)

Comment: The `nice` tool is useful for my case and test.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a foreground process, you can use `ctrl +z` to pause the execution of foreground commands and put the process into the background, where it can be reawakened with fg and put into the foreground

```bash
liruilong@liruilongs:~$ jobs
liruilong@liruilongs:~$ sleep 2000
^Z
[1]+ Stopped sleep 2000
liruilong@liruilongs:~$ jobs
[1]+ Stopped sleep 2000
liruilong@liruilongs:~$ fg
sleep 2000
```

---

In addition to modifying the process priority,Consider using `cgroup` to limit resources when the process starts

If you use `systemd`, you can limit the resources of the process via `cgroup`.

```bash
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$ systemd-run -p MemoryLimit=5M -p CPUShares=100 --unit=sleep-50 --slice=test sleep 50
Running as unit sleep-50.service.
```